# Best way to use: tell application "System Events"

Tags: applescript, tell

I was thinking about what is the best way to use this statement for GUI Scripting:

```
tell application "System Events"
```

There is any difference with

```
tell application "System Events"
   tell process "Finder"
   -- do something with the GUI
   end tell
end tell
```

and

```
tell application "Finder"
   tell application "System Events"
   -- do something with the GUI
   end tell
end tell
```

Moreover It seems that "process" statement can access the GUI while application one can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write

```
tell application "Finder"
  tell application "System Events"

  end tell
end tell
```

you need to keep the "Finder" tell structure open for as long as you need the "System Events" tell structure. This might mess up your code and it could cause problems if multiple apps have conflicting commands.

"System Events" rarely or never conflicts with anything and is needed relatively often. It makes sense to have a very long "System Events" tell structure but it doesn't make sense to have a very long "Finder" tell structure.

Whether you use process or application has nothing to do with it. Both can access GUI scripting, but you may need System Events to do this while controlling an app other than Finder.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you answered your own question. The first example works and is correct, the second example does not work and should not be used.